# How to find out if end of page size has reached in spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am calling ajax on scroll. When ever the html page scroll has reached to end of window, I am requesting data using spring jpa but the problem is even after fetching all the records, when I scroll up and down, the ajax request is sent and data is re-fetched again.

How do I get around this?

Ajax request on scroll:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var win = $(window);
    // Each time the user scrolls
    win.scroll(function() {
        console.log('scroll reached the end. Loading new data');

        if (DataMixin.data.processing)
        return false;
        // End of the document reached?
        if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
//            $('#loading').show();
            DataMixin.data.processing = true;
            DataMixin.data.size++;
            DataMixin.get_data_page_load();
        }
    });
}
```

Spring jpa:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/get_data_on_page_load", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity get_data_on_page_load(@RequestParam(value="page") int page, @RequestParam(value="size") int size) throws Exception {
    String role = "ROLE_USER";
    Page<TopicBean> topics = topicService.findAllByPage(new PageRequest(page, size));
    List<CommentLikes> likes = commentLikesService.findAll();
    return new ResponseEntity(new LoginDataBean( topics, role, "", likes),  HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1203-jdbc42</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Unable to find `hasNextPage()` method for pagination

**Update:** Checking the interface `Page` which extends `Slice` interface has only these methods:

```
package org.springframework.data.domain;

public interface Pageable {

    public int getPageNumber();

    public int getPageSize();

    public int getOffset();

    public Sort getSort();

    public Pageable next();

    public Pageable previousOrFirst();

    public Pageable first();

    public boolean hasPrevious();
}
```

I don't see `hasNextPage()` method. Why?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html#isLastPage() (NB: probably not the current version javadoc)

Comment: @RC. Why is it not there in current version. Its a useful feature. There must be reason they deprecated it?

Comment: It's still there in current release: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html#isLast-- (Page extends Slice)

Comment: @RC Do I have to extend `Slice` interface or something. I don't have method `hasNextPage()` in my IDE intellesense

Comment: @RC. Its there in `Spring Data Core 1.13.0.RELEASE API` and the latest version I found is 1.4

Comment: Please read the javadoc, it's `hasNext()` or `isLast()` in the current version, in your version `Page` does not extend `Slice`, so maybe you could use `next() != null` or something like that

Comment: @RC Its shown in the API but not there in the jar.

Comment: @RC. Actually `page` and `pageable` are different. I am using `pageable` interface not page

Comment: `Page<TopicBean>` that's a page, no?

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript calls the api until the end of the document is reached, not caring, if the last page was already loaded.

If the paging in spring is configured correctly, each response will contain information about the current page, pagesize, available pages.

Your client must evaluate these and if the last page is reached, stop loading.

Spring can also add links to the next page of a response, so you do not need to compute the url on the client.

More about [spring paging here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/paging-chapter.html)